# How do I include a CSS class on a targeted element using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am recently developing a CSS framework that may extend using Bootstrap. I am here to ask for technical advices. Bootstrap has great classes, such as `text-white`, `bg-dark`, etc. However, in CSS, can I include a `text-white` class purely to elements selected using selectors? For instance (I do not know if my code is correct or not):

```css
.some_class {
    class: .text-dark .bg-white
}
```

Comment: you cannot, this not how CSS is designed to work. Either use JS or SASS/LESS

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can you introduce how it works? Knows poorly about them.

Comment: google can do this better than me

Comment: You can't. Your "class:" specification should be exchanged with the CSS property you'd like to set/change for the selected element.